# Errors running pasted code in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to use the basic `sklearn` `iris` datasets code from here:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html

*NOTE: to avoid encoding issues on the 2nd line I changed to Gael from Ga{accent-e}l Varoquaux*

```
print(__doc__)
# Code source: Gael Varoquaux  
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5

plt.figure(2, figsize=(8, 6))
plt.clf()

# Plot the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

# To getter a better understanding of interaction of the dimensions
# plot the first three PCA dimensions
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 6))
ax = Axes3D(fig, elev=-150, azim=110)
X_reduced = PCA(n_components=3).fit_transform(iris.data)
ax.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], X_reduced[:, 2], c=Y,
           cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
ax.set_title("First three PCA directions")
ax.set_xlabel("1st eigenvector")
ax.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_ylabel("2nd eigenvector")
ax.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels([])
ax.set_zlabel("3rd eigenvector")
ax.w_zaxis.set_ticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

If I pick an arbitrary point in the middle to split the code into two pieces and cut and paste them separately - then the code works fine.

[image]

But instead when pasting the **entire snippet** at one time the latter lines get garbled:

```
In [267]: ax.set_title("First three PCA directions")
Out[267]: <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x113726250>

tor")68]: ax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.se.wax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.se.wal("2nd eigenvec
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-81e33d4e9263> in <module>()
----> 1 ax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.se.wax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.seax.se.wal("2nd eigenvector")

AttributeError: 'Axes3D' object has no attribute 'seax'
```

So is there a trick here to be able to paste larger amounts of text into `ipython` ? Note there are ***no tabs*** in the code.  This is for `ipython 4.2.1` with `python 2.7.3` Also: i'm using `iterm2` on OS/X: not sure whether that comes into play or not.

**Update** based on a (good) suggestion this was also attempted via `%cpaste`.  The results are the same:  text gets corrupted when pasting the entire amount as a single unit.

Comment: Have you tried to use `%cpaste`?

Comment: @danielcorreia  Nice idea - but the behavior is the same. pasting in chunks works: as a unit results in corrupted text.

Comment: I can't reproduce it with my ipython 4.1.0. Do you have any additional software that might mess up with clipboard buffer? Is that text copied OK to plain text editor? Was it copied OK here to the SO input form?

Comment: @SergGr   I can reproduce the behavior on *any* python code in ipython with or without `%cpaste` .  afa additional software?  I have a lot on the system: but this is the only program experiencing clipboard issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in `ipython 5.3` . To upgrade from the (broken) ipython 4.X:

```
pip install -U ipython
```

Then everything's kopacetic.